# Mac console log entries are not showing up in 10.8

Tags: macos, console, osx-mountain-lion

I have an app writes to the console log. This feature works on 10.5, 10.6, 10.7 and has stopped working in 10.8

Anyone else has noticed this? If so, what has changed and how to overcome it.

Comment: Any news? I see messages sent to the system log when using NSLog but not printf() or fprintf() - these all worked in 10.7. Is this somehow related to sandboxing or a system-level setting?

Comment: I have noticed the same problem, I'm not seeing any sandboxing errors in the console to indicate that this is causing the problem (unlike other problems I've fixed with mountain lion with over aggressive sandboxing). I wonder if `stdout` that is handed to the JVM is /dev/null rather than whatever the console device is.